# Kuratowski's definition of ordered pairs: proving $(x,y) = (u,v) \iff x=u \text{ and } y=v$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I'm new to set theory and I need to prove the following:

$(x,y) = (u,v) \iff x=u,y=v$ where $(x,y) = \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ as in Kuratowski's definition of ordered pairs.

Now, I think I got the right to left implication as follows:
knowing $x=u$ and $y=v$, by the extensionality axiom we know that two sets with the same elements are equal, so we can conclude that $\{x\} = \{u\}$ and $\{x,y\}=\{u,v\}$. Again by the extensionality axiom we have that $(x,y)=(u,v)$ as we showed that they have precisely the same elements.

What I find some problem with is the left to right implication.
First I wanted to show that two equal sets have the same elements. I did that considering the formulas $x=x \rightarrow \forall z(z\in x \leftrightarrow z\in x)$ and $x=y$, by substitution I get $x=y \rightarrow \forall z(z\in x \leftrightarrow z\in y)$ (let me know if this is a correct derivation or not).

So now given this fact I need to show that $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\} = \{\{u\},\{u,v\}\}$ implies that $\{x\} = \{u\}$ and that $\{x,y\} = \{u,v\}$. I thought of a cardinality argument, we know that the elements of $(x,y)$ and of $(u,v)$ are the same, so $\{x\}$ it's either equal to $\{u\}$ or equal to $\{u,v\}$. However since equality means same elements, it has to be the former case because of different cardinalities. Is this a correct argument? Am I allowed to argue by cardinality? If not, what is the correct way of proving this?

Any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: Looking at the cases $x=y$ and $x \neq y$ may help. This will avoid referring to cardinality.

Comment: Consider cases: from {{x},{x,y}}={{u},{u,v}} assume to the contrary that {x}={u,v}; by Extensionality x=u,v and similarly from {x,y}={u} we get u=x,y and thus $x=u=v=y$